# Generate DDL from 4D database

Tags: ssis, odbc, 4d-database

I have inherited a 4D database that I need to extract all the data from to import to another relational database. The 4D database ODBC driver seems to have quite a few quirks that prevents it from being used as a SQL Server linked server. I can give the gory details if anyone wants them but suffice to say; it's not looking like a possibility.

Another possibility I tried was using the MS SQL Server Import Data wizard. This is, of course, SSIS under the covers and it requires the 32 bit ODBC driver. This gets part of the way but it fails trying to create the target tables because it doesn't understand what a CLOB datatype is.

So my reasoning is that if I can build the DDL from the existing table structure in the 4D database I might be able to just import the data using the Data Import wizard if I create the tables first.

Any thoughts on what tools I could use to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, the 4D ODBC drivers are a (ahem) vessel filled with a fertiliser so powerful that none may endure its odour...

There is no simple answer but if you have made it here, you are already in a bad place so I will share some things that will help.

You can use the freeware [ODBC Query Tool](https://github.com/edwig/ODBCQueryTool/) that can connect to the ODBC through a user or system DSN with the 64 bit driver. Then you run this query:

```
SELECT table_id, table_name,column_name, data_type, data_length, nullable, column_id FROM _user_columns ORDER BY table_id, column_id limit ALL
```

Note: ODBC Query Tool fetches the first 200 row pages by default. You need to scroll to the bottom of the result set.

I also tried DataGrip from JetBrains and RazorSQL. Neither would work against the 4D ODBC DSN.

Now that you have this result set, export it to Excel and save the spreadsheet. I found the text file outputs to be not be useful. They are exported as readable text, not CSV or tab delimited.

I then used the Microsoft SQL Server Import Data Wizard (which is SSIS) to import that data into a table that I could then manipulate. I am targeting SQL Server so it makes sense for me to make this step but if you importing to another destination database, you may create the table definitions from the data you now have whatever tool you think is best.

Once I had this in a table, I used this T-SQL script to generate the DDL:

```
    use scratch;

-- Reference for data types: https://github.com/PhenX/4d-dumper/blob/master/dump.php

declare @TableName varchar(255) = '';

declare C1 CURSOR for 
    select distinct table_name
    from 
        [dbo].[4DMetadata]
    order by 1;

open C1;
fetch next from C1 into @TableName;

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @ColumnDefinition nvarchar(max) = '';

declare @Results table(columnDefinition nvarchar(max));

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE [' + @TableName + '] (';
    declare C2 CURSOR for
        select
            '[' + 
            column_name +
            '] ' +
            case data_type
                when 1 then 'BIT'
                when 3 then 'INT'
                when 4 then 'BIGINT'
                when 5 then 'BIGINT'
                when 6 then 'REAL'
                when 7 then 'FLOAT'
                when 8 then 'DATE'
                when 9 then 'DATETIME'
                when 10 then 
                    case 
                        when data_length > 0 then 'NVARCHAR(' + cast(data_length / 2 as nvarchar(5)) + ')'
                        else 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                    end
                when 12 then 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
                when 13 then 'NVARCHAR(50)'
                when 14 then 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
                when 18 then 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
                else 'BLURFL' -- Put some garbage to prevent this from creating a table!
            end +
            case nullable
                when 0 then ' NOT NULL'
                when 1 then ' NULL'
            end +
           ', '
        from
            [dbo].[4DMetadata]
        where 
            table_name = @TableName
        order by column_id;
    open C2;
    fetch next from C2 into @ColumnDefinition;

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @SQL = @SQL + @ColumnDefinition;

        fetch next from C2 into @ColumnDefinition;
    end
    -- Set the last comma to be a closing parenthesis and statement terminating semi-colon
    set @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL, 1, LEN(@SQL) - 1) + ');';

    close C2;
    deallocate C2;

    -- Add the result
    insert into @Results (columnDefinition) values (@SQL);
    fetch next from C1 into @TableName;
end
close C1;
deallocate C1;

select * from @Results;
```

I used the generated DDL to create the database table definitions.

Unfortunately, SSIS will not work with the 4D database ODBC driver. It keeps throwing authentication errors. But you may be able to load this database with your own bespoke tool that works with the ODBC weirdness of 4D.

I have my own tool (unfortunately I cannot share it) that will load the XML exported data directly to the database. So I am finished.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Boffin, 
Does "inherited a 4D database" mean it's running or that you have the datafile and structure but can't open it?

If it's running and you have access to the user environment the easy thing to do is simply use 4D's export functions. If you don't have access to the user environment the only option for ODBC would be if it's designed to allow ODBC or if the developer provided some export capability.

If you can't run it you won't be able to directly access the datafile. 4D uses a proprietary datastructure and it changed from version to version. It's not encrypted by default so you can actually read/scavage the data but you can't just build a DDL and pull from it. ODBC is a connection between the running app and some other source.

Your best bet will be to contact the developer and ask for help. If that's not an option get the thing running. If it's really old you can contact 4D to get a copy of archived versions. Depending on which version it is and how it's built (compiled, interpreted, engined) your options vary.

[Edit] The developer can specify the schema that's available through SQL and we frequently limit what's exposed either for security or usability reasons. It sounds like this may be the case here - it would explain why you don't see the total structure.

This can also be done with the native 4D structure. I can limit how much of the 4D structure is visible in user mode on a field by field/table by table basis. Usually this is to make the system less confusing to users but it's also a way to enforce data security. So I could allow you to download all your 'data' while not allowing you to download the internal elements that make the database to work.

If you are able to export the data you want that sounds like the thing to do even if it is slow.

Comment: Thank you for your input.

There is a working system with it. I have the 4D SQL Server running and I can connect to it with the 4D ODBC driver. However, the 4D ODBC driver seems to be very very limited. Some things work and many other things just don't. Basically, it doesn't play well with others!

I am able to export the data to XML and I do have a way of importing that into an MSSQL server with a streaming XML parser that I wrote. I had to write my own as I was unable to find an XML library that could handle the large file sizes.

Comment: Part II: I was hoping to bypass the export and import steps as the export step is extremely slow. My import step is very fast but we can still be talking about hours because of the quantities of data. If that is the best I can do, then my job is done. I was looking for improvements in the process.